# vb mysql encoding to hebrew

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encoding, wampserver

*I use Wampserver, visual studio 2015 and vb.

When i add new entries with Hebrew values to database, I get Instead of correct characters a question mark("???").

**It only happens when i add that through code using VB**

***but if i using with phpMyAdmin, it's do it correct.***

this is my code in vb:

```
Dim MyConn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=admin;Password=1234;Database=game")
    Dim BaseTable As New DataTable
    Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from users", MyConn)
    Dim mydatarowscommandbuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(MyAdapter)
    Dim xRow As DataRow
    MyAdapter.Fill(BaseTable)


    xRow = BaseTable.NewRow()
    xRow("id") = 5515
    xRow("Nick") = "דן"

    BaseTable.Rows.Add(xRow)

    MyAdapter.Update(BaseTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

add character set to your connection string, like so:

```
Dim MyConn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=admin;Password=1234;Database=game;Charset=utf8")
```

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation , your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."